# Taking multiple pictures in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

This seems fairly straightforward, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why this will not work. I have similar code that writes an image everytime it reads an image, and that works fine saving the last image seen. I am seriously puzzled as to why this is saving the same image to both img0 and img1. If you guys could shed some light, that would be amazing! Thanks so much for taking the time to read this.

```
#include "highgui.hpp"
#include "imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    VideoCapture stream(0);
    if(!stream.isOpened()){
        cout << "No camera :(\n";
    }
    stream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    stream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    int img_num = 0; 
    int num_pics;
    cout << "How many images do you want to take?\n";
    cin >> num_pics;
    Mat image;
    while(img_num < num_pics){
        cout << "Picture in...\n";
        cout << "3...\n";
        sleep(1);   
        cout << "2...\n";
        sleep(1);
        cout << "1...\n";
        sleep(1);

        stream.read(image);
        imshow("pic",image);
        imwrite(format("img_%d.jpg",img_num),image);
        waitKey(3000);
        img_num += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit to add simple code for saving every frame captured (into the same file, so should ultimately be the last image seen):

```
#include "/home/sarah/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "/home/sarah/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "/home/sarah/opencv-2.4.9/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    VideoCapture stream(0);
    //stream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,1);
    if(!stream.isOpened()){
        cout << "No camera :(\n";
    }
    cout << "After\n";
    stream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    stream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    Mat cameraFrame;
    while(1){
        stream.read(cameraFrame);
        imshow("camera",cameraFrame);
        imwrite("img.jpg",cameraFrame);
        if(waitKey(30) == 13){
            break;  
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "I have similar code that writes an image everytime it reads an image, and that works fine"? where is that code?

Comment: did `imshow("camera",cameraFrame);` show expected result?

Comment: no, it did not @lanpa

Answer (score 0):

here's the culprit:

```
imwrite(filename,image);
```

atm, it will save  *any* image to the same filename(thus overwriting any  previos ones). what you want is probably more similar to:

```
imwrite( format("img_%d.jpg",img_num) ,image );
```

Comment: The issue is not that the file is being overwritten. Because even with this edit, the first image taken is saved into all subsequent .jpg files.